Read from a BigQuery table and write to another table using FastAPI
I am creating an API to read from a BigQuery table and write to another Bigquery table using FastAPI. I am able to read data in the response but unable to write data. The second function shows an error. What is wrong there. Here is my code:
@app.get("/bigquery_data", response_model=List[dict])
async def get_bigquery_data():
try:
dataset_id = "soy-lore-422902-a3.Test"
table_name = "hello"
    sql_query = f"SELECT Index, City FROM `{dataset_id}.{table_name}`;"

    query_job = bq_client.query(sql_query)
    results = query_job.result()

    data = [{"Index": row.Index, "City": row.City} for row in results]

    return data
    

@app.post("/post_to_bigquery", response_model=get_bigquery_data)
async def post_to_bigquery(user: get_bigquery_data):
try:
data_to_insert = [{"Index": get_bigquery_data.Index, "City": get_bigquery_data.City}]
dataset_id = "soy-lore-422902-a3.Test"
table_name = "test"
table_ref = bq_client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_name)
table = bq_client.get_table(table_ref)
    bq_client.insert_rows(table, data_to_insert)


You said that there was an error produced ... however, I couldn't see an error message in your post.  I think you need to update the question with a lot more detail describing the nature of the error.   StackOverflow isn't the place to post code and ask for it to be fixed.  Instead, consider describing what is the core of the error, describe what you have tried to resolve and ask questions to assist you in making progress with the diagnosis and resolution.
